# User profile page title is mistake

Tags: users, caching

I use [login toboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) and [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2). Now I'm logged in as "user1". The I logout and login with "user2". When I then go to the user profile page of user2 I see "user1" in page title.

Clearing the browser cache isn't a solution.

Clearing DRUPAL cache works (but at the moment DRUPAL cache is disabled). Then I see the right username in page title. Is it possible to exclude the user profile page data from DRUPAL cache?

Answer (score 0):

Caching in [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) coused the problem. Disabling the metatags for users solved it.